# Asking Excel to treat \, as a whole syntax not a slash and a comma

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

We have a table dumped from a database as a plain text file. There is a field called Address in that table. Usually when we see the information of that field inside database it is like:

```
   12A StreetName CityName 
   or
   13G StreetName, CityName
```

Now that comma in the second situation is causing the problem. Since data is exported as a text file which is also comma delimited file, we know the comma will be treated as delimiter.

So when I open that text file in Notepad, it looks like this:

```
    previous_field_info, 13G StreetName\, CityName, next_field_info
```

Then later if I want to open this text file in excel it splits the address field into two columns (for those have commas in the address) and that makes the information in the rest fields shifted. What I see in excel now becomes like this:

```
     previous_field_info | 12A StreetName CityName | next_field_info
     previous_field_info | 13G StreetName\         | CityName         | next_field_info
```

So my question is how can I make excel think `\,` is a whole symbol not just a slash and a comma? The current dummy solution is I do a find and replace to remove `\,` but what I want is open that up directly in excel using [Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857)

The reason I do things like this (seems like a big detour) is because I don't have access to that database and the only way to get information is asking the company who maintains the database to send recurring files to me (ideally in csv but now they are sending txt file)

Hope my question is clear and thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you generate the CSV with quotes surrounding fields?

Comment: Hi @rontornambe, can you please elaborate this? I'm not sure how to do that. Would that process be done on the database side? Thanks

Comment: Yes, If that is where the CSV file is created.

Comment: @rontornambe but actually my colleagues and I don't want any extra work from database side (since that database is not hosted in office, and any requirements we ask for may cost extra cost unfortunately ). That's why I want to work on the text file only.

Comment: Why not read the data into Excel un-parsed;so the entire first record goes into **A1**, the entire second record goes into **A2**, etc.  Then parse the records with *VBA* using your desired sub-string rather than a single character.

Comment: can they offer output from select into outfile with fields delimited with double quotes (where your string with a comma is safely contained inside the double quotes somewhere)? So basically it follows the format of LOAD DATA INFILE, and select into outfile. Those two commands just mentioned are connected at the hip in very flexible formatting options

Comment: The only thing you can do in that case is to change the delimited commas to a special character, ex. | or ~ and specify that character as the delimiter in the mySQL import routine.